# Serialize type object to concrete type dynamically

Tags: c#, serialization, dynamic, reflection, types

Hi I am having a hard time solving the following problem.

I am supplied two parameters

- An object (obj) (containing properties with values) which are dynamic
- An string (typeName) (containing a type name which can be anything that matches one of a range of concrete defined types).

Take note that obj is dynamic so I do not have any design time access to any its type or properties.

From this I need to convert this anonymous object to its concrete type initialise it with the values as contained in the object and serialise.

What I have at the moment is this:

```
    public class ExampleObj
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var typeName = "ExampleObj";

        object obj = new
        {
            A = 5,
            B = "xx"
        };

        Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);

        var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(type);
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        serialiser.Serialize(new StringWriter(sb), obj);
    }
```

The last line fail for obvious reasons (the runtime does now know how to convert from type object to concrete type ExampleObj and this is where I am stuck.

I also considered Activator.CreateInstance to get create an instance dynamically but my knowledge and searches does not indicate how I can initialise this instance with the correct values before serialising.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final solution in a controller method that works as required by using a dynamic type.  The key concept to my original question is the fact that you cannot (form what I could gather) automatically do the cast. You need some sort of switching logic doing manual casting based on the types you want to support (or by using a third party tool as suggested in the comments section at the question)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveRule(int? id, ExpandoObject ruleObj, string ruleTypeName)
    {
        Type type = GetTypeFromName(ruleTypeName);
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
        {
            object val;
            ((IDictionary<string, object>)ruleObj).TryGetValue(prop.Name, out val);

            val = AutoMapObjectType(prop, val);

            prop.SetValue(instance, val);
        }

        var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(type);
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        serialiser.Serialize(new StringWriter(sb), instance);

        if (id != null)
        {
            RuleDataAccess.SaveRule((int)id, sb.ToString()); 
        }

        return new JsonResult();
    }

    public static object AutoMapObjectType(PropertyInfo prop, object val)
    {

        if (prop.PropertyType.BaseType.Name == "Enum")
        {
            return Enum.Parse(prop.PropertyType, val.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            switch (prop.PropertyType.Name)
            {
                case "Boolean":
                    return Convert.ToBoolean(short.Parse(val.ToString()));
                case "String":
                case "Int32":
                case "Decimal":
                    return Convert.ChangeType(val, prop.PropertyType);
                default:
                    return Convert.ChangeType(val, prop.PropertyType); //Attempt to convert with implicit casting/conversion, (will fail if explicit cases are not handled)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the next example(for the typename you need to provide the namespace in which the type is contained):

```
var typeName = "YourNamespace.ExampleObj";

object obj = new
{
    A = 5,
    B = "xx"
};

var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj);
Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
ExampleObj instance = (ExampleObj)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
instance.A = (int)props["A"].GetValue(obj);
instance.B = (string)props["B"].GetValue(obj);

//serialize the instance now...
```

If obj was var obj then:

```
var obj = new
{
    A = 5,
    B = "xx"
};

Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
ExampleObj instance = (ExampleObj)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
instance.A = obj.A;
instance.B = obj.B;
```

Comment: You missed the fact that obj is dynamic so I dont have compilte time access to the ExampleObj type or A and B properties